# Is it possible to safely wire nut the hot wires and remove the extra 4 way and 3 way switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I want to install smart lights and 1 single smart switch in my living room. However the lights in my living room currently are on a 4 way. Is it possible (and safe) to just have one wired smart switch and then for the two remaining switches just wire-nut the hot wire together to maintain continuity and remove the switch? Basically I want to make it in essence a single pole switch, but it is wired as a 4 way.

Comment: Building Codes require each room to have a physical switch in certain standard locations, that any human can operate, and that controls a light.   You must retain those switch locations.

Comment: What make and model of smart switch are you wanting to use?

Answer (score 1):

A switch just connects two wires together, so yes, it's absolutely possible to remove a switch and connect the right wires together to keep the light on.  In fact, some smart switches have instructions that tell you to do just that because rather than having 3 or 4 smart switches, you would have one wired smart switch and the rest would be wireless remotes that control the one switch.

The wires that need to be connected are more complicated than just "hot" and "neutral" because 3 and 4 way switch setups have "travelers".  A pretty fool-proof way to determine which wires need to be connected would be use a continuity tester to see which wires the switch is connecting and make sure you wire nut the same wires.  Some wires will end up not being connected and should be capped for future use.

That said, there are usually code requirements to have a room light controllable from all entrances to the room. So while you can remove all but one switch, you may not *really* want to do that.  But, like I mentioned some smart switches have this in mind and make keeping the light functional from all locations easy.

Comment: Okay thank you. Honestly my plan is to replace the other switches that I take out with a smart button, that is wireless, so theoretically, it should still be in code?

Comment: Yea, the idea is that you shouldn't have to walk into a dark room and feel your way to the other side to turn on the light.  Before you start, look up diagrams of how a 4 way switch can be wired, so you know a little more on what to expect when you start to dig into the switches.  Label everything before removing the wires.  Your main wires will be Line, Load, Travellers, Neutrals (normally white), and Grounds (bare or green).

Comment: @Micah label _every_ wire and **take pictures** of the wiring _before_ you remove any wire from any screw!